# Table transformation in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with data in following format:

```
   CarID   Day   DistanceTraveled
   Ford1     1                 10
   Ford1     2                 12
   Nissan1   1                 13
   Ford1     3                 41
   Nissan1   2                 20
   Nissan1   3                 10
...
```

And so on. There are a few hundreds of records in format like this, with a few dozens of cars.

I have to transform it into a following format:

```
Day   Ford1  Nissan1
  1      10       13 
  2      12       20
  3      41       10
```

Is it any fast and automatic way to achieve it in Excel?

Comment: look into pivot-tables, they should get you there fast

Comment: this is more a Super User question - not programming

Comment: just in case you need a bit more support: insert a pivot table, use your example data as source (having it on some worksheet), then put CarID as colums, Day as rows and Distance as values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of an answer:

[image: SO12637799 example]